# Airflow Broken DAG Message - Extra data

Tags: airflow

I am trying to get a DAG to populate in Airflow but am getting the following error message in the Airflow UI.   What does the following Airflow error message mean and how can it be fixed?

```
Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/finance_data_dag.py] Extra data: line 3 column 12 (char 41)
```

NOTE:  Line 3 of the finance_data_dag.py file just includes the following python import statement so not sure what "line 3 column 12 (char 41)" even refers to.

```
import numpy as np
```

Comment: Are you reading any JSON data in the DAG ? Also, did you try commenting out the numpy functionality and validate the DAG?

Comment: Yes, JSON data is being read into the DAG.  I tried commenting out the numpy functionality but keep getting the same error message.

Comment: Does line / column / char relate to JSON data?  If so, what do line / column / char represent in JSON and how can this error message be fixed?